# Why am I getting an error about truncation when running an SSIS job?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssis

hoping someone can help me out. I have no idea what's going on with this job. It runs every week night and always comes back with the same errors.

[image: Screenshot of Error Report]

There are about ten files that are written. We pull the data from our database then convert them to flat files and send it to a third party vendor. Our third party has reported back that all they can view on the error files are the headlines, but no info.

I ran the job manually in debug mode in ssms and there are absolutely no bugs in the package itself. the job succeeded just fine.

Some background - this job has been running with errors since july, which is around the time they set up a new school year as this job is for an educational setting.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, this error tells you there is a truncation issue with the data in the column specified in the error text. Since the data was truncated, and the package was set to fail on truncation error, the package failed. I don't think we can give you much help other than telling you to review the data in that column and compare to your output column specifications--then clean the data or update the column spec.

Comment: @JacobH thank you! What is the error message referring to with the PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED??

Comment: I want to say "PrimeOutput()" is a method in the SSIS code itself, but that's just a guess. The entire package failed, due to a component failing. Note the part of the error  "There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure". So one method called another method. The second failed. The first subsequently fails because the second fails. The second throws a specific error (truncation). The first throws a generic error saying to check the second error.

Answer (score 2):

If I remember correctly SSIS samples the first 1000 rows of a data set to determine the output datatype. If then row 1001+ exceeds the datatype that SSIS chose, you'll get a truncation error. You will need to update offending column to have a longer data type. Look in the advanced menu in your connection.